# Is there a way to import scss files automatically when generating a new component?

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-cli-v7

I have 4 scss files that i use in the majority of my components, i would like if the cli could put the imports inside of the scss file automatically when i do an ng generate component.
Is this possible?

I've done some research on google but have had no luck. I'm using angular 7

i would like this to be automatically added to the top of my components generated scss file: `@import "../../assets/scss/library.scss";`

Comment: personally in your shoes, i'd settle for copy-paste, otherwise, welcome to the wonderful world of [angular schematics](https://blog.angular.io/schematics-an-introduction-dc1dfbc2a2b2).

Comment: @Stavm there's also snippets, like [for VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets), that can be written and used in no time